# Type does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'

Tags: ios, swift

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this does not conform to protocol. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    var session: AVCaptureSession

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        return previewLayer
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, context: Context) {
        // Update the preview layer if needed
    }
}
```

Tried everything I can think of to correct it, but have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [associated type `UIViewType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/uiviewtype) could not be inferred.

You can see the detailed error when you look at the Issue Navigator (⌘5)

[image]

The actual problem is that `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` does not inherit from `UIView` which is a protocol constraint.

According to the suggestion in Duncan's comment and the [documentation of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer) wrap the layer in an `UIView`

```
class PreviewView: UIView {
    // Use a capture video preview layer as the view's backing layer.
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
    
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }
    
    // Connect the layer to a capture session.
    var session: AVCaptureSession? {
        get { previewLayer.session }
        set { previewLayer.session = newValue }
    }
}
```

and change `CameraPreview` to

```
struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    var session: AVCaptureSession

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PreviewView {
        let previewView = PreviewView()
        previewView.session = self.session
        previewView.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        return previewView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PreviewView, context: Context) {
        // Update the preview layer if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer (as usual. Voted.) To the OP: `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is a type of CALayer. You could create a custom UIView subclass that hosted a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` pretty easily. (So have your  makeUIView function initialize and return a UIView that contains a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as its layer class or as a sublayer of the view's layer.)

Comment: Excellent comment, thanks, Duncan. I added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Nice! A simple and elegant implementation of my suggestion. I wish I could up-vote it a 2nd time!